# How to disable TLS in fabric-ca-client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm using fabric-ca-client Version: 1.1.0-beta-snapshot-71974f5 and trying to enroll the CA administrator(i'm playing with fabric-samples/fabric-ca example )

TLS is not enabled on fabric-ca-server.

According fabric-ca-client latest documentation (http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#enabling-tls) TLS is disabled by default.

But, when i execute:

fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://rca-org0-admin:rca-org0-adminpw@rca-org0:7054

it fail because:
[DEBUG] Client TLS certificate and/or key file not provided
Error: Failed to get client TLS config: No TLS certificate files were provided.

In the output i see these messages:

```
Client configuration settings: &{Debug:true URL:https://rca-org0-admin:rca-org0-adminpw@rca-org0:7054 MSPDir:msp **TLS:{Enabled:true**
**[INFO] TLS Enabled**
```

Is TLS enabled by default?

Answer (score 2):

Can you change

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://rca-org0-admin:rca-org0-adminpw@rca-org0:7054
```

to

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u http://rca-org0-admin:rca-org0-adminpw@rca-org0:7054
```

you are using https, which is trying to enforce TLS but could not find any cert file